# Shell script that calculates the previous Monday, Tuesday,... relative to today

Tags: shell, unix, date, solaris

I'm trying desperatly to find a bash or ksh routine that allows me to find for example the previous Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,... preceding today's date. Additonal it has to work on plain vanilla Solaris X and I don't have the GNU date available.

eg: Today = Thursday 2013/01/17 ; Let's say I want to find the last Monday. It has to return: 
2013/01/14

I've managed to find a script on the net that does the job perfectly for all days except in this specific case:
eg: Today = Thursday 2013/01/17 ; I want to find the last Thursday which should give as result: 2013/01/10 ; but instead I get todays date again.

The script used was this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

#Get the nbr of the current weekday (1-7)
DATEWEEK=`date +"%u"`
#Which previous weekday will we need (1-7)
WEEKDAY=$1
# Main part
#Get current date
DAY=`date +"%d"`
MONTH=`date +"%m"`
YEAR=`date +"%Y"`
#Loop trough the dates in the past
COUNTER=0
if [[ $DATEWEEK -eq $WEEKDAY ]] ; then
# I need to do something special for the cases when I want to find the date of the same day last week
  DAYS_BACK=168
  DAY=`TZ=CST+$DAYS_BACK date +%d`
  echo "DAY (eq) = $DAY"
else
    while [[ $DATEWEEK -ne $WEEKDAY ]] ; do
       COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
       echo "Counter is: $COUNTER"
       DAYS_BACK=`expr $COUNTER \* 24`
       echo "DAYS BACK is: $DAYS_BACK"
       DAY=`TZ=CST+$DAYS_BACK date +%d`
       echo "DAY is: $DAY"
        if [[ "$DAY" -eq 0 ]] ; then
         MONTH=`expr "$MONTH" - 1`
           if [[ "$MONTH" -eq 0 ]] ; then
            MONTH=12
           YEAR=`expr "$YEAR" - 1`
           fi
         fi
       DATEWEEK=`expr $DATEWEEK - 1`
     if [[ $DATEWEEK -eq 0 ]]; then
     DATEWEEK=7
     fi
done
fi
echo $DAY/$MONTH/$YEAR
```

Comment: Have you got perl available?

Comment: Try: `date -v1w -v-mon`.

Comment: Sorry, that was the bsd version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(My previous suggestion didn't work as I thought. It was late last night ...)

The key thing is to ignore today, but still loop. Try it like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

#Get the nbr of the current weekday (1-7)
DATEWEEK=`date +"%u"`
#Which previous weekday will we need (1-7)
WEEKDAY=$1
# Main part
#Get current date
DAY=`date +"%d"`
MONTH=`date +"%m"`
YEAR=`date +"%Y"`
#Loop trough the dates in the past
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -eq 0 ] || [[ $DATEWEEK -ne $WEEKDAY ]] ; do
   COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
   echo "Counter is: $COUNTER"
   DAYS_BACK=`expr $COUNTER \* 24`
   echo "DAYS BACK is: $DAYS_BACK"
   DAY=`TZ=CST+$DAYS_BACK date +%d`
   echo "DAY is: $DAY"
   if [[ "$DAY" -eq 0 ]] ; then
       MONTH=`expr "$MONTH" - 1`
       if [[ "$MONTH" -eq 0 ]] ; then
           MONTH=12
           YEAR=`expr "$YEAR" - 1`
       fi
   fi
   DATEWEEK=`expr $DATEWEEK - 1`
   if [[ $DATEWEEK -eq 0 ]]; then
       DATEWEEK=7
   fi
done
echo $DAY/$MONTH/$YEAR
```

Your `` DAY=`TZ=CST+$DAYS_BACK date +%d` `` trick doesn't work for me though. Linux `date` seems to cap it at one day.

Comment: Well, I thought it would fix his problem, obviously. It would have corrupted the final data though. :(   I've changed the solution to one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
today=$(date +"%u")
weekday=$1
curdate=$(date +"%s")
gobackdays=$(($today - $weekday))
if [ $gobackdays -le 0 ]; then
  let gobackdays+=7
fi
SECSDAY=86400
backtime=$(($curdate - $gobackdays * $SECSDAY))
echo $(date -d "@$backtime")
```